# Adding Content-Disposition after an AWS presigned url have been generated

Tags: amazon-web-services, asp.net-core, amazon-s3, pre-signed-url

As Presigned url suggests it is a signed url that can be validated using the signature. I am able to set the Content-Disposition header on the `ResponseHeaderOverrides` in order to change the filename when downloading the file using the persigned url.

```
            GetPreSignedUrlRequest request = new GetPreSignedUrlRequest
            {
                BucketName = bucketName,
                Key = objectKey,
                Expires = DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(duration),
                ResponseHeaderOverrides = new ResponseHeaderOverrides { ContentDisposition =$"attachment; filename=\"MyNewFileName.doc\""}
            };
```

Is it possible to generate the presigned url and then when using that url use a Content-Disposition header or query param in order to ensure a file downloads with a certain name. Currently the desired file name is not known at the time when the presigned url is generated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this is not possible since the specified header is included in the [String to Sign](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/sig-v4-header-based-auth.html).